# Can't get to original size of image after zooming in using a PhotoView

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, android-photoview

I use Chris Bane's [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) to display ImageViews.
After zooming in, I can't zoom out to the originial size of the image. It seems like the borders are too small, but is there any other explanation?

xml photoview setup:

```
    <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id = "@+id/ScreenshotPhotoView"
        android:src = "@drawable/LogoImg"
        android:layout_marginTop = "40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom = "40dp"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType = "fitCenter"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was the fact that I set the `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes to specific values (320x180). 
Solved by changing to `warp_content` or `match_parent`.